# Is GetProcessMemoryInfo thread safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, window

I have an application with several threads running. The application has a safety feature where it has a memory limit. If it exceeds the allowed memory usage, it exits gracefully. This is meant to prevent crashes due to lack of memory.

In the single thread version, I'm using this code for this:

MemoryTester.h

```
class MemoryTester
{
public:
    static bool checkIfMemoryExceedsLimit();
    static void setMemoryLimitInBytes(size_t limit);
    static size_t getMemoryLimitInBytes();
    static size_t getMemoryUseInBytes();

private:
    static size_t s_memoryLimitInBytes;
};
```

MemoryTester.cpp

```
#include "MemoryTester.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "psapi.h"

size_t  size_t MemoryTester::s_memoryLimitInBytes = 0;

bool MemoryTester::checkIfMemoryExceedsLimit()
{
    if (s_memoryLimitInBytes == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return (getMemoryUseInBytes() > s_memoryLimitInBytes);
}

void MemoryTester::setMemoryLimitInBytes(size_t limit)
{
    s_memoryLimitInBytes = limit;
}

size_t MemoryTester::getMemoryLimitInBytes()
{
    return s_memoryLimitInBytes;
}

size_t MemoryTester::getMemoryUseInBytes()
{
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;
    GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*)&pmc, sizeof(pmc));
    return pmc.PrivateUsage;
}
```

Is this code thread safe to use in a multi-threaded application? On its face, it only reads so looks safe, but there might be something happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Without using a lock mechanism such as mutex, those functions are not thread safe.

Comment: General rule of thumb: If the documentation does not explicitly and clearly state that the function is thread safe, it isn't.